Combine TikZ spy with a real picture
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fadings,through}
\usepgflibrary{shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals,spy} 
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usetikzlibrary{spy,calc}
\usepackage{overpic}

\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.fractals,shadows,shapes.symbols,spy}
\tikzset{spy using mag glass/.style={
    spy scope={
      every spy on node/.style={
        circle,
        fill, fill opacity=0.2, text opacity=1},
      every spy in node/.style={
        magnifying glass, circular drop shadow,
        fill=white, draw, ultra thick, cap=round},
      #1
    }}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using mag glass={magnification=3, size=1cm}]
  \draw [decoration=Koch curve type 2]
    decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,0) -- (2,0) }}};

  \spy [red!50!yellow] on (1.6,0.1) in node at (2.5,-0.5); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
\path (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=north west] at ([xshift=4.6cm,yshift=-4.1cm]current page.north west) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{D:/KG_Petra/Allgemeine_Bilder_fuer_Erlebnisberichte/Lupe_mit_Hand_removebg.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
  \end{overpic}
  
\end{document} 

Dear community,
I would like to know whether it is possible to combine a TikZ spy with a real picture in a way that if I move the TikZ spy the associated real picture should move as well to the new position. What I am after is the following : I want to overlay this picture of a real loupe on top of a TikZ spy and move both of them simultaneously (which would look quite nice on e.g. photographs and other pictures). I am aware that in my example both pictures do not match 100% since this is a very time-consuming process if done by hand but to demonstrate what I would like to achieve this should be sufficient. Can this "marriage for all times" be done? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!


